# Ссылки в слайдере

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```
<p class="slider">
<img alt="" src="1.jpg" style="position: absolute;">
<img alt="" src="2.jpg" style="position: absolute;">
<img alt="" src="3.jpg" style="position: absolute;">
</p>
```

И такая jquery-функция для слайдера:

```
$(function(){$('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();setInterval(function(){$('.slider :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slider');},6000);});
```

Пытаюсь сделать картинки ссылками, меняю в функции img на a, но слайдер не работает. Что я делаю не так? Как нужно правильно изменить функцию?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте изменить в js-коде "img" на "а"

Comment: Выше написал, что пробовал уже: слайдер начинает работать некорректно.